Using hyperref's pdfusetitle with RevTeX
I'm wondering whether it is possible to use hyperref's pdfusetitle option in a way that correctly handles the author fields in RevTeX. In practice, RevTeX splits the authorship of the document along many different author fields, and this may modify the expected behavior of pdfusetitle: while I'd like the PDF author field to include the names of all authors, in practice I only get the last input. Is there any simple way to bypass this behavior?
MWE:
\documentclass[reprint,aps,physrev]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\title{Some Title}
\author{Author A}
\affiliation{Affiliation A}

\author{Author B}
\affiliation{Affiliation B}

\maketitle

\end{document}


The metadata of this pdf only mentions Author B (it omits Author A).

add the pdfauthors with the pdfauthor key.

@UlrikeFischer That is a possibility, but I wanted to keep the automated aspects if possible

It is easy for the class to add the authors to the metadata by collecting the authors and then issuing a suitable \hypersetup command. If the pdfmanagement is loaded with \DocumentMetadata this even puts the authors into the xmp-metadata:
\DocumentMetadata{} %optional
\documentclass[reprint,aps,physrev]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\title{Some Title}
\author{Author A}
\affiliation{Affiliation A}

\author{Author B}
\affiliation{Affiliation B}

\hypersetup{pdfauthor={{Author A},{Author B}}}

\maketitle

\end{document}

<dc:creator>
    <rdf:Seq>
     <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">Author A</rdf:li>
     <rdf:li xml:lang="x-default">Author B</rdf:li>
    </rdf:Seq>
   </dc:creator>

It is not easy to do that from the outside. Read a bit in the commented code from revtex in https://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/revtex/ltxfront.dtx and try to figure out where one could collect the author name to understand the problem. From the outside it needs patching into internals of the class. So no, the pdfusetitle from hyperref can and will not support that. Ask the revtex maintainer for better support of such metadata.
